# Subscribe to two image_raws with one function

Tags: ros, opencv, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,
I want to capture pictures from two webcams simultaneously and process them with opencv. I tried to get this work with two image_subscribers, that have the same callback-function. I tried that by editing the code from the cvbridge-tutorial. The result of my editing was, that i got two windows that show both the same picture, switching between the two image raws. So here is my question now:

How do I have to define my subscribers or my callback function to get the two raws seperately in one function to process them both simultaneously?

Solution:
http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters. There you can find an example cpp-code for a policy-based synchronizer function. I've used this example to get my Node working.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96346/subscribe-to-two-image_raws-with-one-function/) by [Bison](https://answers.ros.org/users/4239/bison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2013-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

image_transport has a [special type of subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport#image_transport_Subscribers) specifically for stereo cameras that does what you want, but I think it requires that the timestamps in the image headers be exactly synchronized which is hard to do with webcams.

Your best choice is probably an [ApproximateTime synchronizer](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters/ApproximateTime), which lets you subscribe to two topics with a callback that receives a message from each topic.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bison](https://answers.ros.org/users/4239/bison/) on 2013-11-04**:
There was a very good example on the message_filters entry of the ROS WIKI. Using this example I was able to get the task accomplished. Thank you all for your help. It's good to know that there is a great community that helps everytime it is needed.